# Algorithm that gives a certain permutation of letters from an input value

Tags: algorithm, combinations, permutation

I'm looking for a function that takes a certain input value and transforms it into a certain sequence of letters using the full alphabet.

This is the exact input: output I need:

```
5: aa
6: ab
7: ac
...
51: bu
52: bv
53: bw
...
```

And so on. And it should be able to continue with bigger input values creating combinations like aza, azb, azc or mnki, mnkj, mnkk.

Is this even possible, or do I just have to create all the permutations and store them? This would be easy, but memory intensive and slow and I don't need all permutations, just the one related to the input I'm giving.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What exactly are the inputs and expected outputs of your function?

Comment: Please format your question a bit more accurately. Where is the input?

Comment: I don't have time to write this up now, but it should be possible to treat these as base 26 numbers, shifted so  that 5 = aa.

Comment: But, why 5: aa?

Comment: @Neil It's for a game. It's creating what is called AA notation. I take exponent/3 of a large value and feed it to the function and it returns the correct postfix. The first postfixes are k, m, b, t for kilo, million, billion, trillion, then it goes to AA, AB, AC and so on for number names that no one knows the correct name of anyway. It makes the understanding of large numbers easier. I can also show crazy names like sextillion and septuagintillion but it's hard to understand the progression of that system. Scientific notation is good too, but for non-math people the AA notation looks nicer.

Comment: Ahh, it would be much more clear if you explained this in the question. I don't think anyone is going to understand that; recommend using SI units, https://www.nist.gov/pml/owm/metric-si-prefixes.

Comment: An idler? Any idea what it will be called when it's done or when it will go live?

Comment: @Dave It's called Farm Empire, and it's already out on Steam. Been for a while, just continuously updating and improving. Also, the code for the big numbers and AA notation formatting is available on my Github: https://github.com/ChronoDK/GodotBigNumberClass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use base 26, interpreting the digits as a-z. You'll need to shift this to get 5 = aa.

```
def convert_to_base_26(number)
  return '' if number == 0
  number += 22
  base = 26
  digits = ('a'..'z').to_a

  result = ''
  while number > 0
    number -= 1
    digit = number % base
    result = digits[digit] + result
    number /= base
  end

  result
end


> convert_to_base_26(51)
=> "bu"
> convert_to_base_26(238_225)
=> "mnki"
```

Comment: Not sure where my comment went, but thanks again - works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple python implementation:

```
import numpy as np

def f2(number):
  number = number-5
  if number==0:
    return "aa"
  c=1
  final_string=""
  while number>0:
    r=int(number%26)
    number-=r
    number/=26
    final_string=chr(97+r)+final_string
    c+=1
  if len(final_string)==1:
    final_string = "a" + final_string
  return final_string
```

Comment: >>> f2(680)
'zz'
>>> f2(681)
'baa'


This only works up to 680.

Comment: What are you expecting for 681? This is exactly what I would be expecting...

Comment: I'd expect 'zz' to go to 'aaa' and not 'baa.'

Comment: if you go for base 26 a^n==5 for any n. a^n!=0 doesn't make any sense as far as I understand numbers. I mean you don't count 90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,000 do you?
it's ...98,99,100 just like it's zx,zy,zz,baa.
I don't see how you can properly count with your system.

Comment: The OP specified in the question that they want leading a's: "And it should be able to continue with bigger input values creating combinations like aza, azb, azc or mnki, mnkj, mnkk." No input to your algorithm will result iin 'aza' or 'azb' or 'azc'.